# Plugin missing while using ajax prototype in Grails 2?

Tags: ajax, prototype, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, grails-controller

Hello..I'm using Grails 2 and tried to implement the ajax call from gsp page to my controller..At first library prototype was missing in grails 2 i solve this using command grails install-plugin prototype..Now that error is not coming but not working and different error is coming..

Here by i attached the code..I'm trying simple update second select box if i change the first

As well i added grails.views.javascript.library = "prototype" this line in Config.groovy

```
<code>
     //Controller<br>
        def ajaxgetStrudents() {

            def college=College.get(params.id)
            render college?.students as JSON

        }
        //GSP<br>
        javascript library="prototype" plugin="prototype"<br>
        <g:select id="name" name="name" from="${collegeNames.name }"  
        onChange="${ remoteFunction(controller:'College', action:'ajaxgetStrudents', 

        , onComplete: 'updateStudent(e)',params   :'\'id=\'+this.value '        

            )}
`</code>
```

And i wrote javascript code to fill student select box..This code is not working..In console error coming like this

`` ` Error 2012-10-08 01:16:57,933 [http-bio-8083-exec-6] ERROR [/SampleGrails].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/SampleGrails] threw exception
Message: It looks like you are missing some calls to the r:layoutResources tag. After rendering your page the following have not been rendered: [defer]
    Line | Method
->> 1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor ``

---

|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
`

First i want to make run of this code..??

Next even though i installed the prototype plugin that was not added in my project plugin folder..but it was showing in grails list-plugin -installed command..why it is..??

Thanks..,

Answer (score 0):

1. Prototype has been dropped from Grails 2.1.0 onwards (Not sure about 2.0.3)

Replace

```
<g:javascript library="prototype" plugin="prototype" />
```

With

```
<g:javascript library="prototype" plugin="prototype" />
<r:layoutResources/>
```

Hope that helps. Always refer to the documentation available. This one is a link to upgrading grails, have a lot of info though [Grails 2.1.x](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html)

Comment: <p>Thanks for your answer i'm using the javascript like that only as well i added the<code> `r:layoutResources`</code> it's not working at all.As well thanks for your document link i'm not trying to any up gradation here..problem is even after i installed the prototype plugin i can't able to access it in Grails 2..i want to know how to do that..</p>
Thanks..,

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to install plugin in grails 2.x is to put an entry in BuildConfig.groovy instead of "install plugin" command.

Also to troubleshoot, you could try "Firebug" in Firefox and see if prototype scripts are getting loaded.

Answer (score 0):

### Heading ## - List item

Iam having same issue with prototype,unable to include prototype.js in my grails application.Basically iam using both jquery and prototype and including library using following snippets.

`

The issue comes as gsp unable to load the prototype plugin due to this my prototype ajax is not working and getting following exception.

After rendering your page the following have not been rendered: [defer] Line | Method ->> 1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply missed "***update***" property in the remoteFunction call.